# How can I mock a class that is used in an artisan command for testing?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I have an artisan command which calls another classes function. This function does a get request to another server and I do not want this get request to happen during testing.

My usual solution is to mock that function using mockery however this does not seem to work.

Why is my mock not being called when I call an artisan command using `Artisan::call('command::getFoo')`?

Command class

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Foo;

class GetFoo extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:getFoo';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Get the foo data';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {       
        return Foo::get();  // Returns true
    }
}
```

Testing Class

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Foo;

class FooCommandTest extends TestCase 
{
    public function testThatWeCanGetFoo()
    {
        $fooClass = Mockery::mock(Foo::class);
        $fooClass->shouldReceive(['get' => false]); // Overwrite the foo class to return false instead of true
        $fooData = \Artisan::call('command:getFoo');

        $this->assertFalse($fooData);
    }
}
```

When I run my test it fails because its still getting true back. This means the mockery class is not being called.  What is going on here? How can I test this command?

Comment: The `Foo` class is statically referred to your realworld dependency, that's why it's not using the mock object. You need to get it injected as a dependency into your artisan command. Honestly not sure on how to achieve that on commands but for sure a quick Google would probably show the way.

Comment: [This question should help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647614/laravel-dependency-injection-in-commands)

Comment: Ok awesome thank you. This lead me to a solution.

Comment: Glad to know, feel free to post the answer so others can learn. I'm also curious. Regards!

Answer (score 4):

You could try creating a dummy-child of the root class that the Artisan Facade uses, and override any method that performs an unwanted action.  And then, in your test, call `Artisan::swap($dummyObj);` to replace it.

--

It's not well-documented, I think I came across this when I was looking for a granular way to permit some events to fire in my test, and prohibit others to avoid collateral actions.  So `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::fake()` is a good example of how to use this.

So taking a peek under the hood:

- `config/app.php` defines `Artisan` as pointing to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan`.
- `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::getFacadeAccessor()` defines the name of the facade accessor as the `Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel` interface name.
- And the Kernel interface is bound to a singleton of App\Console\Kernel over in `bootstrap/app.php`.

All totaled, this means any time you call on `\Artisan`, you're actually talking to a reusable instance of `App\Console\Kernel`.

`App\Console\Kernel` extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel`, and *that* is what possessed the `call()` command that you'd want to control the behavior of.

So what you want then is something like this:

```
namespace Tests\Dummies;

use App\Console\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Artisan extends BaseKernel
{
    // This will override the parent's call() and block it from doing anything.
    public function call($command, array $parameters = [], $outputBuffer = null)
    {
        // -- Do nothing instead, or add some debug logging here --
    }
}
```

Then, as the first action inside your test or part of the `setUp()` method, do:

```
$dummyArtisan = app(Tests\Dummies\Artisan::class);
Artisan::swap($dummyArtisan);
```

Note, all of this is untested.  I've done similar things in the past, and can say for sure the theory is solid.  But I don't know if this specific code is.

--

You might also want to look into `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::spy()` and `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::shouldReceive()`.  I just spotted them when looking at the code here to write up this answer, and they have me wondering now if my proposal reinvents the wheel a little bit.  It looks like Facades are designed with a little bit of awareness that they're difficult to Mock, so they have some tools for that baked in.

Comment: Looks interesting, could you expand your explanation?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer to include some example usage.